# Why does FromDigits factor a polynomial output?

Tags: polynomials

The code

```
testseq = {0, 0, 4, -3, 2, 5, 11};
testfunction1[x_] := FromDigits[Reverse[testseq], x];
Print[testfunction1[x]];
testfunction2[x_] := Dot[testseq, Power[x, Range[Length[testseq]] - 1]];
Print[testfunction2[x]];
```

gives me

> `(4 - 3x)x^2 + x^4(2 + 5x + 11x^2)`
>
> `4x^2 - 3x^3 + 2x^4 + 5x^5 + 11x^6`

The first result is surprising, the second as expected. Why do I get the first result?

Comment: `FromDigits[]` is in fact a documented way for producing polynomials that are in [Horner form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornersRule.html).

Comment: Thank you, J.M. that seems a potentially very useful feature. May I ask where is it documented ? Also wouldn't Horner's form according to mathworld be (((((11x+5)x+2)x-3)x+4)x^3 ?

Comment: Programming hint: Save yourself some typing. `f[x]` gives the same result as `Print[f[x]];`. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/3066) for further useful info.

Comment: Thank you m_goldberg, that is a useful hint and an interesting read. I have got into the habit of using ; as a delimiter because it seems to be necessary within a Module.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Apart` or `Expand`

```
list = {0, 0, 4, -3, 2, 5, 11};

FromDigits[Reverse[list], x] // Apart
```

> 4 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 2 x^4 + 5 x^5 + 11 x^6

Why?

Probably because `FromDigits` `Simplify`'s automatically (the factored form is considererd to be the simpler one)

Comment: Thank you eldo. However, when I apply Simplify to 4 x^2 - 3 x^3 + 2 x^4 + 5 x^5 + 11 x^6 it just takes out the factor of x^2.

Comment: Yes, the behaviour of `Simplify` is complex, but you can control it to a certain degree (see Doc and many QAs here)